# Is it not possible to clean web crawl without tagging? Is it impossible to make it clean with regular expression?

Tags: python, python-3.x, html-parsing

```
data = re.sub('<[^>]*>', '', string=html).lower()
```

I want to crawl random pages. However, since it is impossible to scrape only the desired content, I post a question. Is it valid to delete the html using a regular expression after scratching it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can you provide some examples of why it is hard to parse XML and HTML with a regex?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/701166/can-you-provide-some-examples-of-why-it-is-hard-to-parse-xml-and-html-with-a-reg)

Answer (score 0):

html2text library or pextract lib are valid to question